# I used killall5 and my laptop won't boot at all anymore

Tags: kubuntu

Just like it says, I was misled and used the killall5 command. Screen went black and was totally unresponsive. Rebooted and won't do anything but display black, backlit screen. No loading,  no login, just some noises from inside. Please help. Using k ubuntu, newest version.